# How do I enable PHP to run on my website instead of a 405 error?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a HTML/PHP form on my website. The problem is submit just opens a new page displaying my php as text, this is when I open the html file on my computer using Google Chrome. When I uploaded to my hosting service, TK dot com, I get a 405 error when using the form. I've tested on working/downloadable php forms and the same thing happens.

From my understanding, I can't just use php on my site without setting up an environment. I've read I need to use some sort of program to do this (apache). Which kind of confuses me further, how would I enable this type of service, which installs to my computer, to run on my website when my computer is off?

Any tips or guides on how to do use apache for PHP forms on my website or similar that I can be redirected to would be really helpful. Please let me know if any extra information is needed.

Comment: is your website shared hosting? Is php enabled and did your remember your `<?php` tag?

Comment: Hey Roshan, I'm the only one using the hosting service if that's what you mean, I'm not sharing it with anyone. I'm not sure how to enable php on my site, I believe this would resolve my issue. Yes, I remembered the <?php tag at the beginning :)

Comment: by shared I meant out of `shared`, `VPS`, `Dedicated`, `Cloud` which one is it? (If you don't know it's probbably shared) If it's shared just ask the web host how to enable PHP